# How can i trace the location on google map of pc and laptop using MAC address in php?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

I am trying to fetch the location on google map using to MAC address of the pc and laptop. I am work on php wordpress. Can you help me to trace the location on google map??
i am trying below code ";
echo "Your Country is: "; // returns country code by default 
echo getCountryFromIP($ip); 
echo "\n"; // optionally, you can specify the return type // type can be "code" (default), "abbr", "name" 
echo "Your Country Code is: "; 
echo getCountryFromIP($ip, "code"); 
echo "\n"; // print country abbreviation - case insensitive 
echo "Your Country Abbreviation is: "; 
echo getCountryFromIP($ip, "AbBr"); 
echo "\n"; // full name of country - spaces are trimmed 
echo "Your Country Name is: "; 
echo getCountryFromIP($ip, " NamE "); 
echo "\n";
?> 
Note : i get include("geoiploc.php") file download from http://chir.ag/projects/geoiploc/

Comment: u can use the ip of the client $_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"] or $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] but mac?

Comment: mac addresses are not transmitted over the internet. they're useless for geolocation.

Answer (score 1):

you cannot use "MAC ADDRESSES" to track your client locations. 
You can use this library to get your users location by "IP". Here is the 
[Download link and documentation](http://chir.ag/projects/geoiploc/)

```
include("geoiploc.php");
$ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
echo "Your Country is: ".getCountryFromIP($ip);
```

Comment: this code not working....
i get this output  :-
Your IP Address is: ::1
Your Country is: 
Your Country Code is: 
Your Country Abbreviation is: 
Your Country Name is:

Comment: Do you have any errors or any outputs?

Comment: Output :-
Your IP Address is: ::1
Your Country is: 
Your Country Code is: 
Your Country Abbreviation is: 
Your Country Name is:

Comment: can you please edit your question and paste the code you are trying in it?

Comment: Please recheck the question

Comment: Have you put the $ip variable to the begging off your script like my answer bellow?

Comment: Any different solution on that?

Comment: This link will help you very much just read it. http://www.ipinfodb.com/ip_location_api.php

Comment: thanks, i got the solution, thank you helpful

Comment: i'am glad to here that :)

Comment: Can you tell me how to get value Latitude and Longitude from textbox and show location on map using html